# Databound combobox displays valuemember when it loses focus

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, data-binding, combobox

I have a databound combobox (WinForms) that displays the ValueMember, not the DisplayMember when the combobox loses focus.  Here's a simple example where I experience this problem:

```
Public Class Populator

    Public Class Job
        Property JobID As Integer
        Property JobName As String

        Public Sub New(ByVal id As Integer, ByVal name As String)
            JobID = id
            JobName = name
        End Sub
    End Class

    Public Class Person
        Property Name As String
        Property JobID As Integer

        Public Sub New(ByVal n As String, ByVal id As Integer)
            Name = n
            JobID = id
        End Sub
    End Class

    Public Shared Function GetJobs() As List(Of Job)
        Dim joblist As New List(Of Job)
        joblist.Add(New Job(1, "Manager"))
        joblist.Add(New Job(2, "Clerk"))
        joblist.Add(New Job(3, "Unemployed"))
        Return joblist
    End Function

    Public Shared Function GetPeople() As List(Of Person)
        Dim personList As New List(Of Person)
        personList.Add(New Person("Bill", 2))
        personList.Add(New Person("Sally", 1))
        personList.Add(New Person("Mark", 3))
        personList.Add(New Person("Angie", 3))
        personList.Add(New Person("Phil", 2))
        Return personList
    End Function

End Class

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.Populator_PersonBindingSource.DataSource = Populator.GetPeople
        Me.JobBindingSource.DataSource = Populator.GetJobs

    End Sub

End Class
```

Here are some screenshots:

[image: Using databinding designer]

[image: While selecting item]

[image: After losing focus]

Please give me advice on how to maintain the display of the DisplayMember when the combobox loses focus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ComboBox DropDownStyle must be set to DropDownList, not DropDown, to eliminate this out-of-focus behavior.  Apparently, when you drag a field as a ComboBox from the Data Sources tab, the ComboBox DropDownStyle is initially set to DropDown.

I tried this in the sample program listed above and in my real program.  It worked in both cases.

Answer (score -1):

so dont use visual aid use sql code, populate in the cs code

```
       //when you set data source it loses focus to window title
        cmb.datasource = datatable;
        cmb.valueMember = "col1";
        cmb.dispMember = "col2";

        // this does the trick. gives focus back into combobox's list 
        cmb.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList; 
        cmb.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown;
```

Comment: Code only answers are not particularly useful. Please explain how your code works and tell us how this answers the question posted.